# Fetch multiple DIVs from external source

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to display multiple divs from an external page on my own page.
I have the following code to extract the divs. This works in a generic way, but I want it to be more dynamic.

This code extracts content from a given div ID and displays it on my own page.

```
        <?php   
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

//The URL for the external content we want to pull
$html = file_get_contents_curl("https://www.page.com/subdir/");

//parsing all content:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$content = $html;

//The div that includes the content '<div id="divid">'
$first_step = explode( '<div id="ide">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

//Do some magic with the URL
$url2 = $second_step[0];
$url3 = $second_step[8];
$url4 = $second_step[16];

$patterns = array(
    '#\./opening;jsessionid=.*\?#',
    '#<a href=#',
    '#span(.*?)>#'
);

$replaces = array(
    'https://www.page.com/subdir/opening?',
    '<a target="_blank" href=',
    'h1>'
);

//Print the final output
///Merge the result into one variable
$final_output = 
        preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $url2) . 
        $second_step[1] . /* Description -- NOTE: By commenting out this you need to change the H1 margin in the style declaration */
        $second_step[2] . /* From date */
        $second_step[3] . /* To date */
        $second_step[4] . /* Company */
        $second_step[5] . /* Employment condition (full-time/part-time) */
        $second_step[6] . /* Department */
        //$second_step[7] . 
        '<hr>' . /* Horizontal rule */
        preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $url3) . 
        $second_step[9] . /* Description -- NOTE: By commenting out this you need to change the H1 margin in the style declaration */
        $second_step[10] . /* From date */
        $second_step[11] . /* To date */
        $second_step[12] . /* Company */
        $second_step[13] . /* Employment condition (full-time/part-time) */
        $second_step[14] . /* Department */
        //$second_step[15] . 
        '<hr>' . /* Horizontal rule */
        preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $url4) . 
        $second_step[17] . /* Description -- NOTE: By commenting out this you need to change the H1 margin in the style declaration */
        $second_step[18] . /* From date */
        $second_step[19] . /* To date */
        $second_step[20] . /* Company */
        $second_step[21] . /* Employment condition (full-time/part-time) */
        $second_step[22] . /* Department */
        $second_step[22] . 
        '<hr>'; /* Horizontal rule */

///Convert special chars
$converted = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $final_output);

///Display the final result
echo $converted;
?>
```

In this code I have `url2`,`url3` and `url4`to define some parts of the extracted content to modify using `preg_replace` later on. I also have listet `$second_step[xx]`to define what content to display.

As of now I need to list multiple "blocks" of `$second_step[xx]` and multiple `urlxx`to be able to display all child-div's of the parent div with `divid`. The child-div's don't have any ID or class.

I don't know how many DIV's there is to display at any time, so I have to list a lot of these statements in my code. And when I try to seperate every div with `<hr>`, I will get a lot of horizontal rules at the bottom of my page if there is only one, or no DIV's to display.

I also want do be able to display the divs in columns, like two divs side by side.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:** Here's an example of the raw data I'm trying to work with.

```
<div id="ide">
    <div>
        <div class="openingTitle"><a href="./opening;jsessionid=E2A19018E967B4771224A9FA515AFBC0?0-1.ILinkListener-content-contentPanel-openings~view~container-openings~view-0-details"><span style="font-weight:bold;">fagarbeider</span></a></div>
        <div class="openingIngress"><p>Avdeling teknisk drift har ledig stilling som fagarbeider vann/avløp.<br/>Fast, 100 %, ledig snarest.</p></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Utlyst:&nbsp;<span>28.01.2015</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Søknadsfrist:&nbsp;<span style="color:red">01.03.2015</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Selskap:&nbsp;<span>Randaberg kommune</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Stillingstype:&nbsp;<span>Fast ansatt</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Lokasjon:&nbsp;<span>Avd. teknisk drift</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail">

        </div>
        <div>
        <div class="openingTitle"><a href="./opening;jsessionid=E2A19018E967B4771224A9FA515AFBC0?0-1.ILinkListener-content-contentPanel-openings~view~container-openings~view-0-details"><span style="font-weight:bold;">fagarbeider2</span></a></div>
        <div class="openingIngress"><p>Avdeling teknisk drift har ledig stilling som fagarbeider vann/avløp.<br/>Fast, 100 %, ledig snarest.</p></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Utlyst:&nbsp;<span>28.01.2015</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Søknadsfrist:&nbsp;<span style="color:red">01.03.2015</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Selskap:&nbsp;<span>Randaberg kommune</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Stillingstype:&nbsp;<span>Fast ansatt</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail"><i>Lokasjon:&nbsp;<span>Avd. teknisk drift</span></i></div>
        <div class="openingDetail">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: id is id, there shouldn't be more elements with the same id on one page.

Comment: Thanks @n-dru, I looked more closely at the raw data I'm pulling, and have edited my question. There is only one div with the specified ID, but this div has many child-divs without any ID's or Classes.

Comment: But the child-divs of those child-divs have classes....

Comment: You should be working with DOMDocument or similar, not trying to do a bunch of string manipulation and regex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MikeBrant, I'm not to familiar with `DOMDocument`. I had problems pulling for https urls while using Phlanger as PHP compiler for ASP. I therefore had to add a curl function and some a DOM command to manage to pull the data. But that's all I've done with DOM ever, so far. I've added this to the code in the final post. How could I use DOM to get my desired results here?

Comment: @Thorbj You would simply use the content retrieved via curl to instantiate DOMDocument object, and then like use DOMXpath to query for the nodes you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract it with regex:

```
preg_match_all('{<div[^<>]*[^<>]*>(?<content>.*?)</div>}', $content, $matches);
$array_of_contents = $matches[0];
```

Now $array_of_contents is an array containing all those contents that were in those divs. Of course it concerns only those inner divs, they must be on one level.

Comment: So, if there's div's inside the child-divs, theiywon't be included in this array? I've added some raw data to my question, to illustrate what I'm pulling from the external page.

Comment: It will show all content that is inside pairs of <div></div> - I don't know what is the structure you have, experiment with it. If it is one-time thing and you don't need to create universal solutions, do it step by step until you extract all you need.